# HTTP POST Data unreadable until client closes

Tags: ruby, http, sockets, webserver

I am trying to make a web server in ruby using socket for experimentation, and I am unable to get the payload from a post request until the client closes. Then, I can not send any data back when the client does close.

Code:

```
require "socket"
server = TCPServer.new($HOST, $PORT)
client = server.accept
while true
    puts client.gets
#Prints all headers and request but I don't see the actual payload (key=value) until the client disconnects.
end
```

Comment: This is absolutely NOT the correct way to read in an HTTP request, particularly the body. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) for the rules of how to determine the end of an HTTP message properly. You have to read in the HTTP headers first, stop reading and analyze the headers to know the format of the HTTP body, and then read in the body, which can be in several different formats, each of which are formatted and terminated in different ways.

Comment: Do a web search for `ruby http server`, you will find several useful articles for how to implement an HTTP server in Ruby.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I already have separate code for that, I just used the while true statement to be sure that I was reading everything.

Comment: The `while` loop you have shown is NOT reading HTTP messages correctly, not even close. Have a look at [past answers I have posted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) which contain pseudo-code regarding this issue (though most of them are geared towards parsing HTTP responses, but it would take only minor tweaks to parse HTTP requests instead)

Comment: There's a good chance that the payload does not end with an EOL (end of line) marker, so `gets` might hang until the client closes the connection and then return what available data existed (even though it does not end with an EOL)...

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have resolved the issue, by using `if line.chomp.length == 0` to get the end of the headers and `client.read()` to get the data.

Comment: @MatthiasLee that will work only in 1 of several possible scenarios. Read the links I posted in my earlier comment for details of the other possible scenarios.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I think I phrased that wrong. I did look at those links and pieced together what they said and came up with the answer of whaat I did, and it seems to work for all that I need them to.

Answer (score 0):

By using `if line.chomp.length == 0` to get the end of the headers and `client.read()` for the data, I can get the data.